# Dataframe Ploting -Plotly Line chart Single X values vs Multiple Y Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a data frame as shown below

[image]

I need to plot it's line chart using plotly with X axis a "Supply[V]" and Y axis a all the columns

shown in the blue box.

Below is my code ,but no output is coming.

```
  Vcm_Settle_vs_supply_funct = px.line(df_vcm_set_funct_mode1, x = 'Supply[V]', y = df_vcm_set_funct_mode1.columns[5:-9])
  Vcm_Settle_vs_supply_funct.show()
```

But no output is coming may I know where I went wrong

Answer (score 1):

Is the column designation correct? I created a code with the data you presented. It just looks like two lines because the data is almost two different types. I have changed the graph size and added a scale range detail for the y-axis.

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df,x='Supply[V]', y=['VCM_10ms','VCM_20ms','VCM_5s','VCM_DEL1A_10ms','VCNI_DELIA_20ms'])
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=np.arange(-0.1, 1.5, 0.05))
fig.update_layout(height=600)

fig.show()
```

[image]